# How to get all words that are similar to a word the user types Python

Tags: python, list

I am building a program that gets input from the user then checks a list for all words that are similar in letters.

But I only have it set to see if the word the user types is in the list.

```
global words
words = ["Hi", "Hello", "Bye", "His", "Her"]

def get_input():
    word = raw_input("See if there are any matches: ")

    match(word)

def match(word_input):
    word = word_input

    if word in words:
        print("The word  '" + word + "' is in the list")

get_input()
```

Any ideas on how I could print all words that are similar to the word the user typed?

Comment: Similar how? In length? Meaning? Capitalization? Word form (adjective, noun, ...)? Phonetically? Spelling?

Comment: You need to define what "similar" means. Do you mean similar in terms of letters? Then you need to look up Levenshtein distance. If you mean in terms of meaning, this is a _hard_ problem.

Comment: @LukasGraf Like when you type into Google it will start to show similar things like f I type ho it would print words in the list like how, honk, etc.

Comment: @ChinmayKanchi in letters

Comment: The [**fuzzyset**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fuzzyset/0.0.9) module is a way to find similar words by misspelling, typo, capitalisation, etc.

Comment: A [prefix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) might be useful here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending how complex, you may wish to try using [difflib.get_close_matches](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.get_close_matches) (note you may wish to fiddle with the `cutoff=` option, and the other functions in that module which can possibly assist in other things).

```
import difflib

words = ["Hi", "Hello", "Bye", "His", "Her"]
print(difflib.get_close_matches('Hi', words))
# ['Hi', 'His']
```

That can come in useful in some simple cases, but anything more complex, you'd be better off looking elsewhere in terms of spelling, synonyms, abbreviations, typoes, longest substrings etc.. etc... etc...